# Transform LR(2) grammar to LR(1)

Tags: grammar, lr-grammar

I've an exercise in which I have LR(2) grammar and I want to transform in LR(1) grammar. But I don't see how I can do that.
I've this grammar (4 rules) :

- e -> true | false | id | e ^ e | e v e | (e)
- i -> if e then i | if e then i else i | id = e  | (i) | ma
- ma -> a | a ^ ma
- a -> id = e

The problem with this grammar that she produces a reduce/reduce conflict (nobody likes that). 
So I need to change this grammar in LR(1) but I really don't see the algorithm for to do that. Help please :)

Comment: There is a related discussion about [LR(k) to LR(1) grammar conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683692/lrk-to-lr1-grammar-conversion).